# C# 6 switch on nullable long goes to default for real values

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2015, c#-6.0

I have this simple program with a switch on a nullable long:

```
class Program
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  { Console.WriteLine(Test(1)); }

  private static string Test(long? orderId)
  {
    switch (orderId)
    {
      case 1:
        return "1";
      default:
        return "default";
    }
  }
}
```

After compiling in VS 2013 I always get "1" as output.
After compiling in VS 2015 I always get "default" as output.

It only happens if the argument to Test() is a long (not an int).

I've decompiled then il-code and (in my opinion) there is an "conv.i8" missing before comparing the values via "beq.s" (the VS 2013 compiler emits it):

```
  .method private hidebysig static string 
          Test(valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int64> orderId) cil managed
  {
    // Code size       46 (0x2e)
    .maxstack  2
    .locals init ([0] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int64> V_0,
             [1] valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int64> V_1,
             [2] int64 V_2,
             [3] string V_3)
//000011:     private static string Test(long? orderId)
//000012:     {
    IL_0000:  nop
//000013:       switch (orderId)
    IL_0001:  ldarg.0
    IL_0002:  stloc.1
//000014:       {
//000015:         case 1:
//000016:           return "1";
//000017:         default:
//000018:           return "default";
//000019:       }
//000020:     }
//000021:   }
//000022: }
    IL_0003:  ldloc.1
    IL_0004:  stloc.0
    IL_0005:  ldloca.s   V_0
    IL_0007:  call       instance bool valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int64>::get_HasValue()
    IL_000c:  brfalse.s  IL_0024

    IL_000e:  ldloca.s   V_0
    IL_0010:  call       instance !0 valuetype [mscorlib]System.Nullable`1<int64>::GetValueOrDefault()
    IL_0015:  stloc.2
    IL_0016:  ldloc.2
    IL_0017:  ldc.i4.1
    IL_JF17:  conv.i8    // added by me
    IL_0018:  beq.s      IL_001c

    IL_001a:  br.s       IL_0024

//000016:           return "1";
    IL_001c:  ldstr      "1"
    IL_0021:  stloc.3
    IL_0022:  br.s       IL_002c

//000017:         default:
//000018:           return "default";
    IL_0024:  ldstr      "default"
    IL_0029:  stloc.3
    IL_002a:  br.s       IL_002c

//000019:       }
//000020:     }
    IL_002c:  ldloc.3
    IL_002d:  ret
  } // end of method Program::Test
```

Can anyone confirm this?

If I change the switch-Statement to "switch (orderId.Value)" everything works fine. But I'm not sure how many of those statements exists in our code base.

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug to me. You should be able to fix this by replacing `case 1:` with `case 1L:`

Comment: I can repro this *but* the behavior is fixed is you change `case 1:`  to `case 1L:`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Indeed. That fixes it. Data type issue?

Comment: I *don't* get this problem (VS2015, AnyCPU, Debug or Release build, running on Windows 10), latest Windows updates applied.

Comment: A bug indeed and we'll have to wait for the fix ...

Comment: @MatthewWatson are you sure you are using C# 6? I get this with both LinqPad 5 and VS 2015, in a Console application targeting .NET 4.6. The language in Build>Advanced settings is set to default (ie 6)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yep, and .Net 4.6. Not sure why it works for me...

Comment: This is Roslyn bug https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4701

Comment: The bug link is in the duplicate question. [Just checked](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4701) and it seems the error was fixed two weeks ago. Looks like we need to wait for the new compiler's release